# Asyncio interact with the event loop after it's started

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a class that represent a connection a remote server.

```py
class Remote:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._writer, self._reader = None, None
        self._queue = Queue()

    async def start(self) -> None:
        self._reader, self._writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
            ...some host, ...some port)

        while True:
            reading = asyncio.create_task(self.recv())
            writing = asyncio.create_task(self.send())
            await asyncio.gather(reading, writing)

    async def stop(self) -> None:
        self._writer.close()
        await self._writer.wait_closed()

    async def recv(self) -> None:
        data = await self._reader.read(1024)
        print('Recieved:', data)

    async def send(self) -> None:
        if not self._queue.empty():
            message = self._queue.get()
            print('Sending:', message)
            self._writer.write(message)
            await self._writer.drain()

    def queue_message(self, code: int,
                      **kwargs: Dict[str, Union[str, int]]) -> None:
        # Do stuff and return a byte representation of a protocol message.
        message = ServerMessage.write_message(code, **kwargs)
        self._queue.put(message)
```

I want to run the start() coroutine and put messages into queue (see queue_message method) afterwards. How do I do that? I can probably use threads for that, but what are some other options? Maybe I just don't understand the concept of asyncio.

Here's an example of I wanna do.

```py
client = Remote()
asyncio.run(client.start())
client.queue_message(1, username='...', password='...')
asyncio.sleep(5.0)  # Do some other stuff.
client.queue_message(2, listen_port='...')
asyncio.run(client.stop())
```

This is very simple to implement with threads but I wanna explore some other options.

Comment: Do the messages come from somewhere dynamically? Or are they pre-defined in the script?

Answer (score 0):

The code you envisioned won't work because `asyncio.run` creates a new event loop on each invocation, and `Queue`s (and possibly other asyncio synchronization objects) cannot be used across event loops. You should be doing something like:

```py
async def my_app():
    client = Remote()
    await client.start()
    client.queue_message(1, username='...', password='...')
    await asyncio.sleep(5.0)  # Do some other stuff.
    client.queue_message(2, listen_port='...')
    await client.stop()

asyncio.run(my_app())
```

Also note that you should change `self._queue.put` to `self._queue.put_nowait`, or alternatively `await` it and make the function async.